# How to find the kernel of $\pi$

Tags: group-theory

Define a map $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $  by $\pi((x,y))=x$ .Prove that $\pi$ is a  homomorphism and  find the kernel  of $\pi$

**My attempt** :  To show that $\pi$ is homomorphism

Proof :  Take  $(a, b) , (c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ ,  we have  $\pi \left((a,b) + (c,d)\right) = \pi(a+c,b+d) = a+c= \pi(a,b) + \pi(c,d) $ $\implies$ $\pi$ is homomorphism

Im  confused about the kernel i,e how to find the kernel  of $\pi?$

Comment: How do you define kernel?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos   sir      kernel       always contains the identity element of Group

Comment: I am sorry, but that doesn't answer my question. Besides, there is no $G$ in your question.

Comment: im sorry @JoséCarlosSantos sir  it should be like this  $Ker \pi =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2| \pi(x)= e\}$

Comment: There is no $e$ in your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sir   $Ker \pi =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2| \pi(x)= 1\}$  is its correct ?

Comment: No, it is not. The identity element of $(\Bbb R,+)$ is $0$, not $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

You need to find all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\pi((x,y))=0$.

Now it is time to review what a "*kernel*" means.

---

Notes.

Given a (group) homomorphism $f:G\to H$, the kernel of $f$ is all the elements $g$ in $G$ such that $f(g)=e_H$ where $e_H$ is the identity element of $H$.

In your problem:

- $f=\pi$
- $G=\mathbb{R}^2$
- $H=\mathbb{R}$
- $e_H=0$

Comment: i thinks its should be like this $Ker \pi =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2| \pi(x)= 1\}$ im not getting  why $ \pi(x,y)=0?$

Comment: @jasmine: that was a typo. Fixed. $0$ is the *additive identity* for the group $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @jasmine: if you consider $H=\mathbb{R}$ as a *group*, then the operation you consider on $H$ is addition $+$, not multiplication $\times$.

Comment: got it now thanks u  @mrsamy

Comment: @jasmine: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The projection mapping $\pi(x,y)=x$ has kernel $\{0\}\times\Bbb R$, since for all $x,y$:

$x=\pi(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: But the question is "how to *find* the kernel".